# R: how to turn variables to values in dataframe for ggplot

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2

I want to create a barplot that shows the numbers of bugs in 3 different lifestages. For each date (x) I want three bars representing the nr. of individuals in each of the lifestages.

My dataframe from the raw data looks similar like this (simplified example):

```
# create dataframe
date <- c("01/02/2018","14/02/2018","20/02/2018","03/03/2018","15/03/2018")
adult <- c(5,2,3,1,1) 
larvae <- c(6,5,9,7,12) 
nymph <- c(4,4,8,13,10)
df <- data.frame(date,adult,larvae,nymph)

 date adult larvae nymph
1 01/02/2018     5      6     4
2 14/02/2018     2      5     4
3 20/02/2018     3      9     8
4 03/03/2018     1      7    13
5 15/03/2018     1     12    10
```

The only way I know how to plot this with ggplot, is to turn the variables into factor levels of a new variable, say `lifestage`, and put all the counts into a variable `counts`.

That dataframe would look like this:

```
df2
date  stage counts
1  01/02/2018  adult      5
2  14/02/2018  adult      2
3  20/02/2018  adult      3
4  03/03/2018  adult      1
5  15/03/2018  adult      1
6  01/02/2018 larvae      6
7  14/02/2018 larvae      5
8  20/02/2018 larvae      9
9  03/03/2018 larvae      7
10 15/03/2018 larvae     12
11 01/02/2018  nymph      4
12 14/02/2018  nymph      4
13 20/02/2018  nymph      8
14 03/03/2018  nymph     13
15 15/03/2018  nymph      1
```

Plotting this df is easy:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(date, counts, fill=stage)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

To get from df to df2 I have rather large workarounds involving extracting columns, creating new vectors with `rep("stagename",x)` to add to the dataframe, `rbind()` the whole dataframe times the nr of variables I want to turn into factor levels, etc. (I noticed I have used several methods before, but all quite long).

So I have 2 questions:

1) Is there a quick way to turn the different variables into factor
    levels of one new variable? I'm talking about a large dataframe with
    several other variables as well that need to stay.

2) Is there a way to get the same type of barplot without having to
    transfrom the dataframe?

I was trying something like this, but that's certainly not correct:

```
ggplot(data=df) +
  geom_col(aes(x=date,y=adult),fill="blue") +
  geom_col(aes(x=date,y=nymph),fill="green") +
  geom_col(aes(x=date,y=larvae),fill="yellow")
```

I've searched for similar questions, but can't seem to find a problem quite like mine. Also mine is double: if I can make the ggplot without the transformation, it would be better.

I've recently discovered the package `tidyverse` and assumed a solution for the transformation would lie in there, but I haven't come across anything yet that allows me a quick transformation of this kind. 
I'd prefer any solutions using that package if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  gather(stage, counts, -date) %>%
  ggplot(aes(date, counts, fill = stage)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

This should do it, or not?

Comment: It does and it is fantastically short, love it! 
But how does it work? How does R (or gather) know what I mean with "stage" and "counts"? I'd like to understand it so I can play with it myself the next time. The help page does not explain how R links the key and value with the correct column.

Comment: Hey, maybe it would have been more intuitive using `gather("adult", "larvae", "nymph", key = "stage", value = "counts")`. You select the columns that represent values, rather than variables. The key is the column names, which are called `stage` in your data, and the value in your data is `counts`. In my answer, `gather()` will gather all columns except `date`. `-date` (i.e. exclude date) comes from the `dplyr::select()` notation. [This chapter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html#spreading-and-gathering) might be of use to you!